# Low quality UIImage after clipping it to a circle

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage

I am trying to clip a UIImage to make it circular, I am starting with a 140*140px image and then running this code:

```
 //round the image

    UIImageView *roundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:smallImage];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(roundView.bounds.size, NO, 1.0);
    [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:roundView.bounds
                                cornerRadius:roundView.frame.size.width/2] addClip];
    [smallImage drawInRect:roundView.bounds];
    UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    smallImage = finalImage;

    //end round image
```

This works as desired but the quality is very low, the image looks fuzzy and the edges around the circle are jagged. I want to achieve them same affect as:

```
image.layer.cornerRadius = self.thumbnailView.frame.size.width / 2;
image.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Not sure why the quality of the image is so low. Can someone give me some pointers please?

Comment: It is compalsary to clip your UIImage to make it circular..?? you may change Round shape image view and than add your image in imageView..

Comment: I was doing that before but I have many UIImages in a tableview so rounding the image view decreases performance a lot.

Comment: @Kex to me that sounds like you are doing this in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. That's the wrong place to do this. Only a few cells are created and then dequeued. You need to do this once per created cell. Then it will already have the rounded corners for future reuses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to keep scale at 0.f, so it matches the device scale (retina / not retina).

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(roundView.bounds.size, NO, 0.f);
```

You can do also draw a circle like this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 0.f);
CGRect interiorBox = CGRectInset(rect, 0.f, 0.f);
UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:insideBox];
[bezierPath addClip];
[image drawInRect:rect];
UIImage *outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the wrong scale in to UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions. You are passing 1. Use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(roundView.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you actually need to do this to the actual image? Would it not be enough to just make the image view rounded?

You can do this very easily.

```
UIImageView *imageView = // your image view with the image
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 140, 140); // the size you want
imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 70; // make the corner radius half of the size
```

This will display your image cropped into a circle by the image view.

The image remains the same. It is just the display of the image that is rounded.

It's much less expensive too (time and memory).

Doing this in a table will not slow it down. You only need to do this once for each of the dequeued cells. For reused cells you do not need to do this as it is done when the cell is first created.

Comment: Asker wrote that "I want to achieve them same affect as 'image.layer.cornerRadius'", so it seems he knows about this and he needs to change actual image. Anyway, it may be helpful for other people coming here.

Comment: @Vive Ah, lol! I missed that. Well, from the OP's comment it looks like he was using dequeued cells incorrectly which is why he was experiencing poor performance. So the problem was that.

Comment: Nope wasn't the cells, was having massive issues with the table last week, ended up that the problem was changing the corner radius on the all image view's layers. Seems that massively affects the table's scrolling performance if many are used.

Comment: @Fogmeister. I am curious to try out what you just wrote though and see if it works. Maybe it was because I kept doing it even if a cell was reused. Is there a way to find out if a cell is a reused cell from FriendViewCell *cell = (FriendViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]; ?

Comment: @Kex don't do it in that method at all. In the `FriendViewCell` use the `init` method (or `awakeFromNib` if coming from storyboard/nib). And put it in there. Those methods are only run when the cell is created. When the cell is dequeued they are not run. Also, use the `prepareForReuse` method to blank out labels and images etc... If the size of the imageView changes at all then you might be better doing it in `layotuSubviews`.

Comment: Oh, that makes a lot of sense. The prepareForReuse sounds like it will help me later too. I'll give it a shot. Thanks

Comment: @Kex No worries. What you may be experiencing in the poor scrolling performance is not the rounded corners but the resizing of the image. If you display a 8 MP picture at 140x140 then the processing is in shrinking the image. This will be fixed by your resize function that you are using as it shrinks the actual image. But if the images are small and you are just rounding them then you shouldn't have too much of a problem.

Comment: Tried the rounded corners in the awakeFromNib, very noticeable lag. There is no resizing done in the the UITableViewCells. The code above is actually for when a user take a photo on the camera for the profile picture. After the picture is taken it's resized and rounded and saved to the server. Table just loads ups the images no resizing or anything needed. Works well like this now.

Comment: @Kex ah, ok. Well glad you got it fixed. Def put stuff like this into `awakeFromNib` in the future though. Anything that only needs to be done once per cell.

Comment: I will do. Is prepareForReuse a good place to set a placeholder image also? I have images downloading, right now the placeholder is being set in cellForIndexPath, is it better to put that in awakeFromNib for the init and also prepareForReuse?

Comment: Yeah that would be a good use. Think of it as setting the cell back to default. So yes, set the placeholder image here. It means that in `cellForRow` you only have to worry about what the cell will look like when populated. You don't need to worry about setting it to default first.

Comment: Thanks, I actually have another question related to this that I will post later. Don't wanna go too off topic here. What you posted makes a lot of sense and will make my code cleaner. cheers